# Column Data filter

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a column of data that I'd like to 'filter', this filter has two distinct components.

Step 1:

- Move down through a column of data
- Identify gaps in blocks of data
- Gaps less than a nominated cell value are filled with a value of 1

Step 2:

- Move down through the same column of data as Step 1
- Identify data groups that consist of an amount of rows lower than the nominated cell value
- Blocks of data that are smaller than the nominated cell value are deleted

I have already created a macro that fills in gaps in a data group of less than a certain cell value (Cells(1, 15).Value), shown below.

Here's what I have so far, I've started writing a macro for the second step but can't get past a syntax error. Also shown below is an example of raw and filtered data.

The syntax error is one thing, I'm struggling with how to carry out the second step, so help would be appreciated.

Cheers

```
Option Explicit
Sub FillInTheBlanks()
'
' FillInTheBlanks Macro
'
'Declare integers and decimal characters

Dim iCol As Long, Last As Long, i As Long
    Dim iBlank As Long, BlankMode As Boolean, iCount As Long
    Dim j As Long, i1 As Long, iFullCount As Long 'Declare integers, boolean and decimal characters


    iCol = ActiveCell.Column 'Column identified by active cell
    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Row 'Determine end of nominated range
    iBlank = 0 'iBlank starts at zero
    iFullCount = 0 'iBlank starts at zero
    BlankMode = False 'BlankMode starts as False


    For i = 4 To Last 'Start at row 4 and go to the end of column
        If BlankMode Then  'If the next cell is empty

            If Cells(i, iCol) = "" Then
                iBlank = iBlank + 1 'If an emty cell is detected increase iBlank by 1
                iCount = iBlank 'Count the spaces

            Else
                  For j = i1 To i - 1 And iCount < Cells(1, 15).Value
                      Cells(j, iCol).Value = 1
                  Next j
                  BlankMode = False
            End If

        Else

            If Cells(i, iCol) = "" Then
                iBlank = 1
                i1 = i
                BlankMode = True
            End If

        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub EraseSpikes()
'
'
'
'

Dim iCol As Long, Last As Long, i As Long
    Dim iFullCount As Long
    Dim p As Long


    iCol = ActiveCell.Column
    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Row

    iFullCount = 0



    For i = 4 To Last


            If Cells(i, iCol) = 1 Then
             iFullCount = iFullCount + 1
             p = i
            Else
                  If iFullCount < Cells(1, 15).Value And Sum(Range(Cells(p, iCol),Cells(p-Cells(1, 15).Value,iCol))=0 And Sum(Range(Cells(p+iFullCount, iCol),Cells(p+iFullCount(1, 15).Value,icol))=0

                  End If

            End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

```
1   1           1
2   1           1
3   1           1
4   1           1
5   1           1
6   1           1
7   1           1
8               
9               
10              
11              
12              
13              
14              
15              
16              
17              
18              
19              
20              
21              
22              
23              
24  1           1
25  1           1
26  1           1
27  1           1
28  1           1
29  1           1
30  1           1
31  1           1
32  1           1
33  1           1
34  1           1
35  1           1
36  1           1
37  1           1
38  1           1
39              1
40              1
41  1           1
42  1           1
43  1           1
44  1           1
45  1           1
46  1           1
47              1
48  1           1
49  1           1
50  1           1
51  1           1
52  1           1
53  1           1
54              1
55              1
56              1
57              1
58  1           1
59  1           1
60  1           1
61  1           1
62  1           1
63  1           1
64              1
65              1
66              1
67              1
68              1
69  1           1
70  1           1
71  1           1
72  1           1
73  1           1
74  1           1
75              1
76              1
77              1
78              1
79              1
80              1
81              1
82  1           1
83  1           1
84  1           1
85  1           1
86  1           1
87  1           1
88              
89              
90              
91              
92              
93              
94              
95              
96              
97              
98              
99              
100             
101             
102             
103             
104             
105             
106             
107 1           
108 1           
109 1           
110 1           
111 1           
112 1           
113             
114             
115             
116             
117             
118             
119             
120             
121             
122             
123             
124             
125             
126             
127             
128             
129             
130             
131             
132             
133             
134             
135             
136             
137 1           1
138 1           1
139 1           1
140 1           1
141 1           1
142 1           1
143             1
144             1
145             1
146             1
147             1
148             1
149             1
150             1
151             1
152             1
153             1
154             1
155 1           1
156 1           1
157 1           1
158 1           1
159 1           1
160 1           1
```

Comment: your macro actually looks much more complex than you described, also it's not clear which is your exact issue with it. Please edit your question to make it clear and of a digestible size.

Comment: Thanks Máté, I've made some edits so hopefully things are a bit clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax error is with this line:

```
If iFullCount < Cells(1, 15).Value And Sum(Range(Cells(p, iCol),Cells(p-Cells(1, 15).Value,iCol))=0 And Sum(Range(Cells(p+iFullCount, iCol),Cells(p+iFullCount(1, 15).Value,icol))=0
```

Breaking it down:

```
Sum(Range(Cells(p, iCol),Cells(p-Cells(1, 15).Value,iCol))
```

You're missing brackets, and `Sum` isn't a VBA function. Instead, you'd use `Application.Sum`

I've written it slightly differently based on what I *believe* you actually need. Let me know if this works for you.

```
Sub EraseSpikes()
'
'
'
'

Dim iCol As Long, Last As Long, i As Long, j As Integer, startOfBlock As Integer

    startOfBlock = -1   'Initialise startOfBlock. -1 means we're not in a block yet


    iCol = ActiveCell.Column
    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 4 To Last   'Begin loop from row 4 (?) to the end

            If Cells(i, iCol) = 1 Then          'If we find a 1...
                If startOfBlock = -1 Then       'And the block hasn't yet been started...
                    startOfBlock = i            'Mark this line as the start of our block
                End If
            Else                                'If we don't find a 1...
                If startOfBlock = -1 Then       'And we're not in a block...
                    GoTo nextLoop:              'We skip the rest of this until we're in a block
                End If
                If (i - startOfBlock) < Cells(1, 15).Value Then     'We didn't skip, so we're in a block.
                                                                    'we check if (current row number - start row number)
                                                                    'is less than the value in Cell(1,15) (Not equal to?)

                    For j = startOfBlock To i                       'It was, so we loop through all the rows in that block blanking them
                        Cells(j, iCol).Value = ""
                    Next j
                End If

                startOfBlock = -1                                   'Reset to not being in a block
            End If
nextLoop:
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: @Sandie No problem - when you're happy your problem is solved don't forget to mark the answer correct using the checkmark on the left of the answer that helped you :)

Comment: Thanks Jonno, this has been so helpful. Your code works although I need to add two additional criteria to the identifier. These ask for a nominated cell range before and after a block to be empty before deleting the block.     If (i - startOfBlock) <= Cells(1, 15).Value And Application.Sum(Range(Cells(i, iCol), Cells(i + Cells(1, 15).Value, iCol))) = 0 Then  -  This additional criteria works but the second shown below doesn't as I think the it is trying to look at rows before Row1? And Application.Sum(Range(Cells(i-startofBlock, iCol), Cells(i-startofBlock - Cells(1, 15).Value, iCol)))=0

Comment: Yes, it'll be looking for a negative row which can't be done. You could add the second criteria within my `If (i - startOfBlock) < Cells(1, 15).Value Then`, and do something like `If i - startOfBlock - Cells(1, 15).Value > 0 Then` *next line* `If Application.Sum(Range(Cells(i, iCol), Cells(i + Cells(1, 15).Value, iCol))) = 0 And Application.Sum(Range(Cells(i-startofBlock, iCol), Cells(i-startofBlock - Cells(1, 15).Value, iCol)))=0 Then` *delete block* `End If` *next line* `End If`

Comment: Thanks again Jonno, this wasn't just a Google search for answers, I appreciate you spending time on this.

Comment: @Sandie Not a problem - I have no idea what you're trying to achieve but hope it works out :)